# How to use json tags in anonymously nested struct?

Tags: go

I have the following anonymous struct

```
func wrapHal(selfHref string) interface{} {
    return struct {
        Links struct `json: "_links"`{ # does not work, returns error "expected expression"
            Self struct {
                Href string
            }
        }
    }{
        Links: struct {
            Self struct {
                Href string
            }
        }{
            Self: struct {
                Href string
            }{
                Href: selfHref,
            },
        },
    }
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to rename from `Links` to `_links` when I serialize to JSON using `json.Marshal`

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Tag should be placed after the struct definition. `Links struct { ...} <JSON_TAG_HERE>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the base structure.

```
    type s struct {
        Links struct {
            Self struct {
                Href string
            }
        } `json:"_links"`
    }
```

is the correct syntax